# C# and ASP.NET MVC : BackgroundService problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I got some problems with `HostedService` / background classes in my ASP.NET MVC project.

What I need is a timer that process some functions every X seconds and when those functions reach goals, go to stop and repeat process.

I have implemented the service in StartUp file as below :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddTransient<INetLogger, Log4NetLogger>();
    services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationSetting, ConfigurationSetting>();
    services.AddSingleton<BackgroundService, StrategyLoops>();
    services.AddSingleton<IStrategyManager, StrategyManager>();
    services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}
```

I have created the class that contains the inheritance and I have the builder for a `UnitOfWork`.

In this class I got the `ExectuteAsync` function that should contain the logic of program.

```
public class StrategyLoops : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork Uow;

    public StrategyLoops(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Do logic stuff
            await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what's my problem ?

When I start the program, nothing happens. I put some debug breakpoints, but the compiler don't pass through code and the logic doesn't start.

This logic calls server's API and there is running while loop, if I don't have a timer, the server kick me out for overload requests.

The project was little different at start, I got a "StrategyManager" class that implements different logic

```
services.AddSingleton<IStrategyManager, StrategyManager>();
```

For probing logic, I was calling the methods directly from `HomeController`, but now I don't know how to start ...

Notice that I'm a noob of OOP ...

`StrategyManager`:

```
 public class StrategyManager : IStrategyManager
 {
    public bool IsDivisible(decimal x, decimal n){}

    public decimal SpotTradeWallet(){}

    private const int indexValore = 0;
    private const int indexQuantity = 1;
    private const string SELL = "sell";
    private const string BUY = "buy";

    public void Strategia1(IUnitOfWork uow, String symbol, decimal startValue, decimal 
    startQuantity){}

    public void Strategia2(IUnitOfWork uow, string POBsymbol, string SOsymbol, string 
    HTsymbol, string SBsymbol, string Ssymbol){}
}
```

The other problem, my knowledge problem, is that I don't understand if I can implement the Background service also in the `StrategyManager` class, so I can call it more easily from a view.

Lots of thanks to anyone who will answer me

Comment: Do you add```services.AddHostedService<StrategyLoops>();
``` to ConfigureServices method?

Comment: Sure, as you can see in first code partition. Added as Singleton
services.AddSingleton<BackgroundService, StrategyLoops>();

Comment: Or do you mean something else ? In this case, what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services) for registering background services. They're supposed to be registered using `AddHostedService`, which [registers them as `IHostedService` implementations](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs). Your code is registering them as `BackgroundService` implementations.

The host is [looking for `IHostedService` implementations, not `BackgroundService` implementations](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc7f2f9c1a80c262055757331acca25d2748d381/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L61).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllersWithViews();
  services.AddTransient<INetLogger, Log4NetLogger>();
  services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationSetting, ConfigurationSetting>();
  services.AddHostedService<StrategyLoops>();
  services.AddSingleton<IStrategyManager, StrategyManager>();
  services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you forn answer. After 2 days of trouble i have find the problem by myself, but thank's for answer anyway. Best regards.